# How to add service references in VC++ with VS2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, c++-cli, service-reference

With VS2008, we can add web services after setting VC++ projects to CLR.

But VS2013 doesn't give any option to add service references after doing this change.

**Does anyone know how to add it?**

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Run wsdl.exe with the /language:cpp option from the Visual Studio Command Prompt.

Answer (score 2):

> Run wsdl.exe with the /language:cpp option from the Visual Studio Command Prompt.

by [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26808794/how-to-add-service-references-in-vc-with-vs2013#comment42191450_26808794)